# Formatting a date in my titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: iphone, date

I am working on a simple to do list application, and I am wanting to set the date in a normal format in the titleForHeaderInSection part of my uiTableView. But I am having some issues. It works to an extent, but is giving me way too much information, it shows:

2009-12-01 00:04:10 -0700

in the field where I'd just like it to show the date that the item was created, and ideally in a more normal format, without the specific time. Can you please help me figure out what I need to change? Thanks!!

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm 'on' EEEE MMMM d"];
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"newDateString %@", newDateString);
// For US English, the output is:
// newDateString 10:30 on Sunday July 11
```

You should also read [Date Formatting Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)